# AzureDevOps : Any way to get the folder paths and the corresponding list of PullRequests created. Looking for RestAPI

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We are using Azure Devops.
Here I am looking for a RestAPI that gives us the FolderPath under which the list of all PullRequests created and details of pull requests.

Appreciate any leads here. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Azure DevOps Services REST API - Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) documentation? They have a fairly robust API that also goes beyond the PRs.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response. Yes I did explore on the documentation. But I could find the RestAPI search criteria for a particular branch in the repository. Below is the example link. But I did not find an API to retrieve all the Pull Requests that are created under a specific folder/subfolders.



https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1#targeting_a_specific_branch

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Pull Requests that are created under a specific folder/subfolders". Pull requests always involve branches. Do you mean any pull requests that contain changes made within a specific folder/subfolder?

Comment: Yes the meant the same. Looking for RestAPI that gives me the Pull requests contains the changes made within a specific folder/subfolder. Please let me know incase you have any suggestions. Thank you